# python mock_open assert several write calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking

I am trying to test some code that does logging.

```
logfile = open(file_name, 'w')
logfile.write("blah1")
logfile.write("blah2")
```

I'd like to assert that both blah1 and blah2 get written.  My test function looks like this:

```
def test_it(self):
    logger.open = mock_open()
    logger.time.time = Mock(return_value=12345)

    logger.run_me()

    logger.open.assert_called_once_with('test_12345.log', 'w');
    file_handle_mock = logger.open()
    file_handle_mock.write.assert_called_with("blah1")
    file_handle_mock.write.assert_called_with("blah2")
```

But it gives me an error:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: write('blah1')
Actual call: write('blah2')
```

How can I properly test multiple calls to the write function?

Versions:
Python 2.7.6
mock==1.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs, `assert_called_with` and `assert_called_once_with` only pass if the call is the most recent one<sup>1</sup>.  The trick us to use `assert_any_call`, or `assert_has_calls`.

```
file_handle_mock.write.assert_has_calls([
    mock.call('blah1'),
    mock.call('blah2'),
])
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>It's kinda hidden in the docs for [assert_any_call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_any_call), so we can't really blame you for missing it...</sup>